# Second fundamental form of a map between Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

For a (suppose smooth) map $\phi: M \rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are smooth Riemannian manifolds, the *second fundamental form of $\phi$* is defined as $\nabla d\phi$.

My problem is I can not see how this Levi-Civita connection works: if I compute $\nabla_{e_j} d\phi (e_i)$ for $e_i,e_j \in TM$, I am computing the derivative of $d\phi(e_i)$, which is an element of $TN$, respect to $e_j$, which is an element of $TM$.

Maybe this means that $\nabla_{e_j} d\phi (e_i) \equiv\nabla_{d\phi(e_j)} d\phi (e_i)$?

Comment: You need to be very careful about defining things here. You have Levi-Civita connections on both $M$ and $N$. What does $\nabla$ mean in your formula and what is $d\phi$? (It's best to think of it as a section of a bundle.)

Answer (score 2):

When we write $\nabla d \phi$, we make a lot of omissions and identification in order to highlight what is essential. Unfortunately, this does not help in calculations. In order to be very careful, as Prof. Shifrin suggests, quite a bit of technical work needs to be done, which I am quite lazy now to reproduce and only can recommend the classical textbooks or [Joel Persson's Master's thesis](https://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/students/Joel-Persson-MSc.pdf) where everything is laid down nicely.

The bottom line is that $d \phi$ should be considered a section of $T^*M \otimes \phi^* TN$ with the coupled connection $\nabla^{T^*M \otimes \phi^* TN}$ which is induced by the Levi-Civita connection on the sections of $TM$ (vector fields on $M$), but on the sections of $\phi^* TN$ (vector fields **along** $M$) it is acting as the pull-back Levi-Civita connection .

Comment: You mean $T^*M\otimes\phi^*TN$, I believe.

Comment: @TedShifrin oops, you are right. Thank you. Sorry, I was hurrying.